# import in R json file from drive

Tags: r, json, import, gdrive

I have few json files on google drive and i'm trying to import them into R.
the code used is:

```
json_file <- "name_of_the_link"
json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(json_file), collapse=""))
```

and I receive this message:
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection

Comment: (1) that error suggests that the file or URL/link do not work, no way for us to know for real; (2) I suggest `jsonlite::parse_json` in place of `fromJSON`, mostly as a defense mechanism in case the original link includes something that looks like a file/link and is therefore pulled/opened/queried instead of just parsed.

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with json. Test `txt <- readLines(json_file)` by itself to confirm this. Try that and report back.